# Dynamic cast down the class hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti, dynamic-cast, null-pointer

I read the following from C++ Primer (5th edition):

> A dynamic_cast has the following form:
>
> 1. dynamic_cast<`type*`>(e)
> 2. dynamic_cast<`type&`>(e)
> 3. dynamic_cast<`type&&`>(e)
>
>    ...
>
> In all cases, the type of e must be either a class type that is publicly derived from the target type, a public base class of the target type, or the same as the target type. If e has one of these types, then the cast will succeed. Otherwise, the cast fails.

In other words, the author claimed that if the type of e is a public based class of the target `type`, then the cast will succeed, so I tried the following code:

```
class Base{
  public:
  virtual void print(){std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;}
};

class type: public Base{
  public:
  virtual void print(){std::cout << "Derived..." << std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    Base* e = new Base;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<type*>(e); // line 15
}
```

Unfortunately, the dynamic cast on line 15 failed (we get a nullptr), why?

Comment: The book is wrong. `dynamic_cast` can cast across the type hierarchy: you can (attempt to) cast from a pointer of type `A*` to an unrelated type `B*`, and it may succeed if that pointer actually points to an object derived from both `A` and `B`. What *is* required for the cast to succeed is that the dynamic type of the object to which the cast applies have the target type as its accessible base class.

Comment: Being a public base class is a *requirement*, but not enough in itself. The pointer must also point to `Base` that is part of a derived object.

Comment: @BoPersson "If e has one of these types, then the cast will succeed. Otherwise, the cast fails" --  I believe the author meant that being a public base class is a necessary and sufficient condition for the cast to be successful, not just the former.

Comment: @JakeFreeman The code works but I wonder why the cast fails, i.e., why the output is 0.